# Docker non root user cant write to anonymous volume

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile with an anonymous volume like this:

```
...
RUN adduser -D nonrootuser
RUN chown nonrootuser /app/log

USER nonrootuser
VOLUME /app/log

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build a/app.jar app.jar

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app/app.jar"]
```

When my app starts it can't write to `/app/log`.  How should I solve this?  I want to have an anonymous volume and not a named one.

Comment: How are you running the container?  Is it possible you're using an old copy of the anonymous volume that has different ownership?  Do you need the volume at all, or would it be okay to use the temporary container filesystem if nothing else is mounted?

Comment: a) just `docker run` with variables and image b) I run 'prune volume'. Result was not changed c) yes I need

Comment: when I remove volume from dockerfile app is working fine but data is lost.